# MySQL>>Regex>> Extract string without double quotes, dash & commas

Tags: mysql, regex

It seems a simple problem and have gone through available solutions but nothing fits perfectly here.
My data in MySQL table column looks like

```
ID FlowerName
1. Rose
2. "Red" Rose
3. Rose "20 Natural" pink
4. Rose "White shade" dark
5. Lotus-Dark
6. Lotus plain
7. Tulip
8. Daisy
9. Poppy, fresh
10. Lily_Pure
…
..
```

I want to have this data in csv for further processing (which I am able to export through script)
But this data should be in string format only

1. So either we can **exclude all the records having quotes, commas, underscore and dash**
   or
2. we can **extract all the data without having quotes, commas, underscore and dash**

I have tried following regex in simple 'select' statements

> > Select FlowerName from flowers where FlowerName is not NULL and FlowerName REGEXP '^[^"]*';

> > Select FlowerName from flowers where FlowerName is not NULL and FlowerName REGEXP '^[^,]+$';

> > Select FlowerName from flowers where FlowerName is not NULL and FlowerName REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9_ ,]';

> > Select FlowerName from flowers where FlowerName is not NULL and FlowerName REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9]';

> > Select FlowerName from flowers where FlowerName is not NULL and FlowerName REGEXP '[\w]';

No regex from above statements are working correctly for all combinations :(

Can anyone help me with this simple issue?

TIA

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE FlowerName NOT RLIKE '[\"\_]'`

Comment: Quotes, commas, underscore and dashes are totally fine to use in CSV data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew >> Yep. But I am using those values as input somewhere.. There 'string 'input is mandatory :)

Comment: Not sure why I got down vote for this question :/ I put my efforts and did research before asking the question.. but still …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following regex.

```
^[^",_-]+$
```

**Details**:

- `^`: start of a line
- `[^",_-]`: match a single character not present in the list `"`, `,`, `_`, `-`
- `+`: match between one and unlimited times
- `$`: end of a line

I also tried to excute code on mysql.

```
create table flowers(ID integer, FlowerName varchar(100));
insert into flowers(ID, FlowerName) values(1, "Rose");
insert into flowers(ID, FlowerName) values(2, "\"Red\" Rose");
insert into flowers(ID, FlowerName) values(3, "Rose \"20 Natural\" pink");
insert into flowers(ID, FlowerName) values(4, "Rose \"White shade\" dark");
insert into flowers(ID, FlowerName) values(5, "Lotus-Dark");
insert into flowers(ID, FlowerName) values(6, "Lotus plain");
insert into flowers(ID, FlowerName) values(7, "Tulip");
insert into flowers(ID, FlowerName) values(8, "Daisy");
insert into flowers(ID, FlowerName) values(9, "Poppy, fresh");
insert into flowers(ID, FlowerName) values(10, "Lily_Pure");

select FlowerName from flowers where FlowerName is not NULL and FlowerName REGEXP '^[^",_-]+$';
```

Result

```
FlowerName
Rose
Lotus plain
Tulip
Daisy
```